# Check whether two button be pressed simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

I'm trying to check whether two button were pressed simultaneously. Only when both are pressed at the same time should an action be performed. Yes I could each time, when one of the buttons is pressed, start a timer. And could compare the time until the second button has been pressed. 
Perhaps there is a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use gesture recognizers instead of buttons for this.

Comment: Do you mean they need to be pressed at the same moment (or within a very short time)? 
Or do you mean simply that they are down at the same time (like a shift key and a character on a keyboard, or record and play on a tape recorder)?

Comment: Yes I mean at the same moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an `NSDate` instance variable for the time of the last button press
- Initialize it to 0.
- When either button is pressed, check if there is a time in the variable
- If none, put the current time in it and return.
- If there is a time, check to see if it is close enough

  - If not close enough, put the current time in the variable and return.
  - If close enough, set the time to 0 and perform any action.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I unterstand the principle, but could you give me an example? It would help me a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton` has a `state` property. When button one is pressed, check the state of button 2, and vice versa.

Here's how you check the state:

```
BOOL buttonPressed = self.button1.state & UIControlStateHighlighted;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if you touch both buttons at the same time. Only if you touch and hold one, and then touch the other.

Comment: If've asked the question above to establish what he means. But it wouldn't fail in the situation that they are both pressed at the same time. One event has to be processed before the other, and the second one will notice that the first button is already pressed.

Comment: I've noticed events getting processed at the same time on different threads. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Fixed the test: added `.state` and changed `UIControlStateSelected` to `UIControlStateHighlighted`. Note that the buttons have to be connected to touchdown, not the usual touchup. It is not important if they are on different threads.

Comment: Just tested this with both touch down and touch up events It works even with simultaneous touches.